# How might one handle AJAX behavior in a web app where HTTP header-based authentication times out out-of-band?

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, timeout, session-timeout

I have a client with RSA Cleartrust in place on top of an ASP.NET MVC/Web API app.

Cleartrust provides information on authenticated users via HTTP header. When a protected URL does not have a valid, non-expired Cleartrust cookie, users are redirected to the Cleartrust logon on another server, then back to the protected application.

The application uses a lot of JavaScript to make async calls. When the user's session times out with Cleartrust, subsequent AJAX calls using jQuery made from the protected app result in errors, but not the usual redirect behavior one sees at the browser pageload level.

There is no push notification of session timeout, so there's no passive means of avoiding these errors.

1. Set a cookie upon login (probably difficult due to varying entry points) that expires in 30 minutes. Use it as a flag; when it expires, reload the page and force the user to Cleartrust logon, which will then deliver them back to the same page in the protected app. Then again I guess this cookie could be set on every pageload, creating sliding expiration. Check cookie, then reset cookie. This would work for all entry points.
2. Use a JavaScript timer that, every 35 minutes, checks for valid session. (Less than 30 minutes would simply renew an existing session.) If session has expired, force page to reload, which delivers the user to the Cleartrust logon page. They are then redirected back to the same page they were on in the protected app.
3. Add some error handling logic in the jQuery success code block that properly interprets the redirect to the logon page, and avoids the JSON parsing error seen otherwise. When this logic finds a redirect, again, force a page reload, then logon in Cleartrust and redirect back to same page in protected app.

Obviously #1 & #2 are brittle around the 30 minute timeout not being reconfigured.

1) I think is the easiest option.

3) I think is the best option, but certainly not easiest. I can't precisely recreate this state in my environment, only attempt to mock it, so it's hard for me to test thoroughly.

Comment: What do the errors look like? Can you parse the error replies, identify them as errors, and then have your program notify the user via some modal or some other means?

Comment: That would be option #3 Jonathan.

Comment: Yes, it is. And it's the way to do it right.

Comment: Actually as it turns out, jQuery can be set up to handle specific status codes. So I'm going to wire it up for a 302, no ugly parsing efforts required as in #3, and no lack of ability to fully test.

Answer (score 0):

statusCode as documented on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ will serve my purposes perfectly. The user receives a 302 redirect when their session is expired. I can act on that 302 reliably.

Comment: Nice. Please show your code so future readers can benefit from the example.